# Problem with URL path when I applied SEO friendly URL

Tags: seo, htaccess, php, url-rewriting

I was working on PHP project and making SEO friendly URL Like,

OLD : `http://example.com/list_product?q=men-top-wear`

New : `http://example.com/list_product/men-top-wear`

Here is my *.htaccess* file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^list_product$ /list_product/%1? [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^list_product/(.*)$ list_product.php?q=$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

It's working well but my link path has been changed to: `http://example.com/list_product/images/logo.png`

But I need this to be:
`http://example.com/images/logo.png`

It adds `list_product`, but it's not working. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Whilst the linked question deals with missing CSS, the underlying problem (and resolution) is exactly the same... using _relative_ URL-paths to your static resources.